# Is it possible to get all the images saved in imagelibrary at a time into my application in iphone sdk?

Tags: objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0

I want to get all the images stored in my device library and I want to add all those images to my application . Is it possible if so please give me idea

Thank you
Praveena Nalajala

Comment: you found any help for this?. I need the same thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible in iPhone SDK 3.0 (which you have tagged your question with), using public APIs.

In iOS 4.0, you can use [ALAssetsLibrary](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to access the device's saved image library.

Answer (score 0):

yes possible.

https://github.com/elc/ELCImagePickerController

http://www.icodeblog.com/2011/03/03/update-elcimagepickercontroller/